# railsのフロントから飛ばしてコントローラー内で受け取る値がparams以外で記述されている。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

railsのプロジェクトで　`def create`　内で使用される `params` が `コントローラの単数名_params`　となっているのですが、これはrailsの仕様でしょうか？
そのような設定ファイルが見当たらなくて気になっています。

詳しい方教えて頂けないでしょうか。
他に不足している情報があれば教えて頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

おそらくscaffoldで生成されたコントローラだと思うのですが、`コントローラの単数_params`というのはストロングパラメータと呼ばれるメソッドで、そのコントローラのファイルの`private`メソッドとして定義されていると思います。

```
pravate
def hoge_params
  params.require(:モデル名).permit(:カラム1, :カラム2)
end
```

例えば上記の場合、`permit`に指定されているカラム1とカラム2以外のパラメータがPOSTされてきても無視されます。

ストロングパラメータはマスアサインメントという脆弱性の対策のためにrails4以降に導入された機能で、悪意のあるパラメータの操作を防ぐためのものです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！継承先に記述してありました！